# How to find out what process is printing pages on remote printer through STDIN?

Tags: printing, cups, stdin, lpr, lp

Some process sends output of my console over `stdin` to remote print server. If there is cups printer configured, it prints it. So I need to keep cups disabled. I suspect something is running `lp` or `lpr`. It usually starts some time after I compile big project.

Is there a way howto find after what process run it?

The only thing I know is to see the job in the cups web history http://remote-print-server.example.com:631/:

```
ID        Name       User Size  Pages   State
foo-11612 (stdin)    user 1634k Unknown completed at Tue 06 Feb 2018 12:49:30 UTC
```

UPDATE: It's about printing through `stdin`. I don't have any local logs except `journalctl`, as the printer is not connected locally :-(. The text above is copied from cups web log.

Comment: It is normally messages from the kernel ring that appear on the console. This can be stopped by running "dmesg -D"

Comment: is this in the console for the system, or any random terminal you've opened?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, but as you can see from tags, it's really about printing on printer, **not** `echo` (`bash`) or `printf` (C). **It's about `cups`, `lp` and `lpr`)**.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your console is `/dev/ttyS0`, you could search `/proc/<pid>/fd` for file descriptors with that device:

```
$ sudo ls -l /proc/[0-9]*/fd
```

Then search that output for either `1 -> /dev/ttyS0` (standard output) or `2 -> /dev/ttyS0` (standard error), and you'll be able to find the IDs of any processes that are using the console for stdout or stderr.

Alternatively, if you have `lsof`, you can use that:

```
$ sudo lsof /dev/ttyS0
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
agetty  3955 root    0u   CHR   4,64      0t0 4046 /dev/ttyS0
agetty  3955 root    1u   CHR   4,64      0t0 4046 /dev/ttyS0
agetty  3955 root    2u   CHR   4,64      0t0 4046 /dev/ttyS0
```

Comment: Please, see update, the question is about real printing, `cups`, `lp` and `lpr`.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, assuming that this is writing to your shell's stdout, you should be able to find potential processes using `lsof` to check who's connected:

```
% lsof -t "/proc/$$/fd/1"
23717
26269
```

You can then find out who's is doing writes using a tracing program like `strace`, `perf trace`, or by using eBPF:

```
% strace -s 1000 -ewrite -p "$(lsof -t "/proc/$$/fd/1" | paste -sd,)"
[pid 26680] write(1, "foo\n", 4)        = 4
[pid 26680] write(1, "bar\n", 4)        = 4
[pid 26680] write(1, "baz\n", 4)        = 4
```

Comment: Please, see update, the question is about real printing, `cups`, `lp` and `lpr`.